# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject' in django

Tags: python, django

I have this problem catching the pk of the Selfie model, i'm trying to save a comment, but i have this error, the mistake is in the CreateComment class in the views.py, please guys i need a hand

**in models.py**

```
class Selfie(models.Model):
    selfie_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    selfie_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    selfie_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",
        width_field="selfie_width",
        height_field="selfie_height",
        )
    selfie_height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    selfie_width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    selfie_favorite = models.BooleanField()
    selfie_user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    selfie_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.selfie_title)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.selfie_title

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    body_comment = models.TextField()
    timestamp_comment = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post_comment = models.ForeignKey("Selfie")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.body_comment[:20])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body_comment[:20]
```

**in views.py**

```
class SelfieDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = "SelfieDetail.html"
    model = Selfie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SelfieDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm
        if self.request.POST:
            context['form'] = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['form'] = CommentForm()
        return context

class CreateComment(FormView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    success_url = '../login'
    template_name = "SelfieDetail.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(CreateComment, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            form_kwargs['instance'] = models.Selfie.objects.get(pk=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return form_kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form']
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.comment_user_id = self.request.user
        #obj.post_comment_id = kwargs={'pk': Selfie.pk} .... self.request.POST.get('comment')
        obj.post_comment_id = self.request.GET.get( 'post_comment_id' )
        obj.save()
        return redirect('/login')
```

**template**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'createComment' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">(Comentar)</button>
</form>
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'stylizrApp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  221.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/src/stylizrApp/views.py" in form_valid
  49.         obj.save()

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1064.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/l/Desktop/stylizr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /comment/
Exception Value: null value in column "post_comment_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (22, asda, 2016-08-05 17:18:07.513423+00, 1, null).
```

Comment: You need to post the full traceback. It's hard to figure out where the error is given that you post a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the `user` to `comment_user_id` because it expects an integer. Either of the following would work:

```
obj.comment_user_id = self.request.user.id

obj.comment_user = self.request.user
```

Comment: but how to get the Selfie id pk? that my dilema

Comment: Thanks, for the **user.id** that saved a part of my life